# Regular expression or operator

Tags: .net, regex, xval

I'm trying to write a regular expression to test as string. The string must start or end with an alphanumeric character.

eg.

```
test - OK
test$ - OK
$test - OK
$ - not OK
$test$ - not OK
```

I can test the beginning with `^\w.*$` and the end with `^\w.*$`.

But I can't seem to combine them into something like `^.*\w$ | ^\w.*$`.

Does anyone have any ideas or even a better regex for this purpose?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using C# .NET, but we're using the xVal extension which will greate a javascript function to test the string on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
^\w.*|.*\w$
```

Comment: I used this one, as it was the shortest. Thanks to all answers though.

Comment: `^\w|\w$` is like 4 characters shorter :)

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

```
/^\w|\w$/
```

Although `\w` includes `_` so if you only want letters and numbers:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]|[0-9a-zA-Z]$/
```

---

```
var tests=['test', 'test$', '$test', '$', '$test$'];
var re = /^\w|\w$/;
for(var i in tests) {
  console.log(tests[i]+' - '+(tests[i].match(re)?'OK': 'not OK'));
}

// Results:
test - OK
test$ - OK
$test - OK
$ - not OK
$test$ - not OK
```